# discord.py storing message method

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am first timing editing messages and I stumbled on one annoying problem:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content="hi")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    msg.edit(content="HI")
```

This code works just fine, but I want to store `msg` for example in `.csv` file to prevent losing it after unloading it from ram.  It will stop working.

I know it's possible to store the id and then let the client find it or **just not unload it from ram**, but isn't there any way to do that?

Comment: Discord.py objects like a message have methods that can't be "pickled" and stored. That's why you save the message id if future reference is needed.

Comment: @Ali, I guess it's hard to 'pickle' a discord.py `Message`, but it's probably easy to pickle and store a message's `content`. You can actually pickle a message, but implementing and writing the code for it would take some time. It's not impossible. The message can be deleted. In that case, the message's `id` would be useful to get and check if the message is still there or deleted. I suggest storing it in a JSON file, or even a TXT would be better; I don't understand why CSV files are even used. Try writing the code to store it; if you have any problems with it, you can always ask here.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I mean at that point you're just storing content and maybe some metadata (channel id, guild id, etc). You wouldn't really be 'pickling' the `Message` but rather prob making another object like a dict storing those attributes which, is easy to do. If it's a few specific messages then a JSON file could suffice but still not recommended as a discord bot generally has high read/writes which could corrupt the files, instead a database should be used.
Also storing message contents has privacy implications and such data needs to be encrypted.